# Problem with encrypting /var/www and ikiwiki

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, encfs, ikiwiki

I tried to encrypt `/var/www` with `encfs`. To do so I did following:

`mv /var/www /var/www.bak`
`mkdir /var/www_enc`
`encfs --public /var/www_enc /var/www`
`cp -a /var/www.bak/* /var/www/`
`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

I tried it with my local `ikiwiki` (`localhost/myikiwiki`). Browsing worked perfectly but when I tried to save an edit I got the following error message:

```
Failed to save your changes.

Your changes were not able to be saved to disk. The system gave the error:

Your changes are preserved below, and you can try again to save them.
```

However if I revert the changes, everything works perfectly.

I don't understand this, since the encrypted `/var/www` folder should look to the outside world exactly as the old unencrypted version would (especially because I used the `--public` switch).

Any idea what may be wrong and how to fix it?

System Info:

- Ubuntu 11.04
- Apache2: 2.2.17-1ubuntu1.2
- ikiwiki version 3.20110124ubuntu1

Comment: What's the point of encrypting it, then?

Comment: It's on a laptop, when the laptop is shutdown it is encrypted on the hard drive.